# How to read Hebrew text using System.IO.FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream

Am I missing something or does System.IO.FileStream not read Unicode text files containing Hebrew?

```
    public TextReader CSVReader(Stream s, Encoding enc) 
    {

        this.stream = s;
        if (!s.CanRead) 
        {
            throw new CSVReaderException("Could not read the given CSV stream!");
        }
        reader = (enc != null) ? new StreamReader(s, enc) : new StreamReader(s);
    }
```

Thanks
Jonathan

Comment: You're missing something. What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: That kind of blatant anti-semitism is exactly why so many people haven't switched to C# yet.

Comment: Which Encoding are you passing in?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130290/how-to-read-text-files-with-ansi-encoding-and-non-english-letters

Answer (score 5):

The FileStream is nothing but a byte stream, which is language/charset agnostic. You need an encoding to convert bytes into characters (including Hebrew) and back.

There are several classes to help you with that, the most important being [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) and [`System.IO.StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The stream might be closed.

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canread%28VS.80%29.aspx) on `CanRead`:

> If a class derived from Stream does
>   not support reading, calls to the
>   Read, ReadByte, and BeginRead methods
>   throw a NotSupportedException.
>
> If the stream is closed, this property
>   returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager that you're simply not using the right encoding.  Chances are you're passing in `Encoding.Default` or `Encoding.ASCII` when you should actually be passing `Encoding.UTF8` (most common) or `Encoding.Unicode` to that method.

If you're sure that you're using the right encoding, post the full code and an example of the file.